# .htaccess rewriterule empty parameters note found error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess RewriteRule code:

```
RewriteRule ^urunler/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$  urunler.php?kategori_id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I am going to this url "example.com/urunler/hi-tech-cadirlar/1".There is an error in this URL. But "example.com/urunler/hi-tech-cadirlar" this url go to 404 not found page. 
I can not make pagination. I dont want the error Empty paramters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two different rules, one for pagination and another without pagination:

```
RewriteRule ^urunler/([\w-]+)/?$  urunler.php?kategori_id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^urunler/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$  urunler.php?kategori_id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: @anubhava Dear If you have a time can you check my question for me ? [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020054/remove-php-extension-from-subfolder-url)