# Remove php extension from subfolder url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to add some other page for my project. But i have one question about php extension.

So i am using htaccess for some url like following htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^friends/([\w-]+)/?$ /friends.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^followers/([\w-]+)/?$ /followers.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^status/([\w-]+)/?$ /status.php?msgID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^following/([\w-]+)/?$ /following.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^followers/([\w-]+)/?$ /followers.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, i have created photos.php from the details folder and the link is :

```
<a href="http://www.name.com/details/photos.php">Go Photos</a>
```

When i click the Go Photos link i want to remove that url php extension like

```
http://www.name.com/details/photos
```

I have still tryed some answer from stackOverflow

[Remove .php extension from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736591/remove-php-extension-from-url)

[Remove php extension from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837043/remove-php-extension-from-url)

but that answers gives me 404 page not found.

How can i remove .php extension from url anyone can help me here ?

Comment: Are you asking how to use javascript to remove an extension from a hyperlink before its clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension (explicitly written) for friendly URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need additional rules for removing `.php` extension.

Use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^status/([\w-]+)/?$ status.php?msgID=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(following|followers|friends)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule (?:^|/)([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Dear i have used also some other think like : `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.name.com/explore/explore">` the explore is explore.php if i use your codes then i can not open explore page it says Internal Server Error. How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: for example https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: oww also following,followers and friends links given 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @anumbhava it is localhost:8888 from my imac . I don't know how can i check error.log

Comment: page looks like this : [IMAGE](https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/13495499_304514426548390_8716549526317603430_o.jpg)

Comment: i found it : `[Fri Jun 24 21:57:35 2016] [error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost:8888/mustafa`

Comment: Now the rules working fine Thank you. Just one problem here this link gives me same error 500 Internal Server Error : <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.name.com/explore/explore"> . I don't have explore file just i have explore.php . I used rel="canonical" before it is working fine but now it is not working.

Comment: i used this think : https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/  from bottom area in this website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115554/discussion-between-anubhava-and-devstud).

Comment: @anubhava I have a question from you, what should i do to work you answered htaccess codes both (subfolders,subdomains and root folders) ? Because for example: `RewriteRule (?:^|/)([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]` is not working in subfolder ? I need help about this

Comment: That rule would work in sub-folder also. Just make sure you comment out `RewriteBase /` line for `subfolder/.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava Do you mean i need to change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase subfolder/` ? If yes that means we should almost write subfolder name in htaccess ?

Comment: If .htaccess is inside the subfolder then it is good to have appropriate `RewriteBase` set.